# OnClick events for dynamic LinkButton

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic, linkbutton

I have a series of Hide/Show LinkButtons dynamically created. Each button corresponds with a GridView. I want to have the OnClick event of the button Hide or Show the GridView. How do I reference the specific corresponding GridView in the HideButtonClick method. I used a counter **num** to make each LinkButton.ID unique `ID="hidebutton" + num`.

```
            LinkButton lbShow = new LinkButton();
            lbShow.ID = "lbShow" + num;
            lbShow.OnClientClick = "HideCourse_btnClick";
            lbShow.CommandArgument = "" + num;
```

And in the event method I want something to the effect of

```
protected void HideCourse_btnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    grdvw1.Visible = false
}
```

where the ID **grdwv1** is generated by adding the CommandArgument **num** to the GridView **grdvw**

Comment: Do you want to achieve this with asp.net (server side)? or client side with javascript or jQuery? Can you also post your HTML produced with your code?

Comment: i'm not very familiar with ASP.NET but should event referencing be written as lbShow.OnClientClick += HideCourse_btnClick;?

Answer (score 0):

Consider to use a [Repeater](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.aspx) with a LinkButton inside the ItemTemplate. Then use Repeater [ItemCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemcommand.aspx) event to handle LinkButtons click events.

Answer (score 0):

add this line

```
LinkButton1.CommandName = "cmdnum";
```

add RowCommand event to your gridview

```
protected void yourgridview_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "cmdnum")
        {
            this.FindControl("grdwv" + e.CommandArgument).Visible = false;
//i am assuming other gridview is on your .aspx page
        }
    }
```